# Cosets and finite groups of orthogonal operators on the plane

Tags: group-theory, dihedral-groups

Can someone show me how to compute the left cosets of the subgroup $H=\{1, x^5\}$ in the Dihedral group $D_{10}$

I know that $D_{10}$ is generated by two elements $x$ and $y$ such that: $$x^{10}=1, y^2=1 \text{ and } yx=x^{-1}y$$

Comment: What have you tried? This is -essentially- a straight forward calculation, using the fact that $a\in bH$ if and only if $b^{-1}a\in H$. Each coset should contain precisely two elements? (Why?)

Comment: @user1729 so what is your a and b here

Comment: (If you want examples, try searching on here for some. For example, I quickly found [this example](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150066/finding-the-left-and-right-cosets) and [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/524147/list-all-cosets-of-h-and-k).)

Comment: My $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary elements of $D_{10}$. So, for example, $xH=\{x, x^6\}$ because $x^6x^{-1}=x^5\in H$.

Answer (score -1):

This is -essentially- a straight forward calculation, using the fact that for two elements $a, b\in D_{10}$ we have that $a\in bH$ if and only if $b^{−1}a\in H$. Each coset contains precisely two elements (why?)

For example, $xH=x^6H$, because $x^6\in xH$ as $x^{-1}x^6=x^5\in H$. Then because each coset contains two elements we have that $xH=\{x, x^6\}$.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to provide some constructive criticism?